# Catenary with Manipulate

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, curve

I would like to represent a Catenary-curve in Mathematica, and then allow the user to Manipulate each of the parameters, like the Hanging-Points' position (A,B), the cable's weight, the force of gravity etc.?

Comment: Does the shape of a catenary depend on the weight of the cable or gravity? I thought it didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

First, define the catenary:

```
catenary[x_] := a*Cosh[(x - c)/a] + y
```

Now I can either find the parameters `a`, `c` and `y` of this curve numerically, using `FindRoot`:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{root},
  (
   root = FindRoot[
             {
                catenary[x1] == y1, 
                catenary[x2] == y2
             } /. {x1 -> pt[[1, 1]], y1 -> pt[[1, 2]], x2 -> pt[[2, 1]], y2 -> pt[[2, 2]], a -> \[Alpha]}, 
             {{y, 0}, {c, 0}}];
   Show[
    Plot[catenary[x] /. root /. a -> \[Alpha], {x, -2, 2}, 
     PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, AspectRatio -> 3/2],
    Graphics[{Red, Point[pt]}]]
   )], {{\[Alpha], 1}, 0.001, 10}, {{pt, {{-1, 1}, {1, 1}}}, Locator}]
```

Alternatively, you could solve for the parameters exactly:

```
solution = Simplify[Solve[{catenary[x1] == y1, catenary[x2] == y2}, {y, c}]]
```

and then use this solution in the Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[
 (
  s = (solution /. {x1 -> pt[[1, 1]], y1 -> pt[[1, 2]], 
      x2 -> pt[[2, 1]], y2 -> pt[[2, 2]], a -> \[Alpha]});
  s = Select[s, 
    Im[c /. #] == 0 && 
      Abs[pt[[1, 2]] - catenary[pt[[1, 1]]] /. # /. a -> \[Alpha]] < 
       10^-3 &];
  Show[
   Plot[catenary[x] /. s /. a -> \[Alpha], {x, -2, 2}, 
    PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, AspectRatio -> 3/2],
   Graphics[{Red, Point[pt]}]]
  ), {{\[Alpha], 1}, 0.001, 10}, {{pt, {{-1., 1.}, {1., 0.5}}}, 
  Locator}]
```

The `FindRoot` version is faster and more stable, though. Result looks like this:

[image]

For completeness' sake: It's also possible to find a catenary through 3 points:

```
m = Manipulate[
  Module[{root},
   (
    root = 
     FindRoot[
      catenary[#[[1]]] == #[[2]] & /@ pt, {{y, 0}, {c, 0}, {a, 1}}];
    Show[
     Plot[catenary[x] /. root, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, 
      AspectRatio -> 3/2],
     Graphics[{Red, Point[pt]}]]
    )], {{pt, {{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou verymuch!!! Perfect answer! That was exactly what I was searching! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi nikie!
Is it possible to get the Controls of the (x,y) of each of the 3 points? so that the user can modify it with manipulate, or set a value to the x-coordinate/y-coordinate? because now i can just modify the points with the locator (with the mouse) and there isnt any variator (dimmer).. 
Another question, can I delete the rest of the curve? i mean above the points A and B ? 
Thankyou very much!!

Comment: @ZelelB: Sure, just make 6 variables for the 6 coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3), put the values into the optimizer, and let the Plot range from {x,Min[x1,x2,x3],Max[x1,x2,x3]}.